# Doctrine - Error with command database:create or schema:update -f

Tags: php, postgresql, doctrine-orm, php-pgsql

I need to change some calculations in a CRM but when I've receive the zip file I've unzip it in WAMP, it's use Symfony so I've done the install with composer and update. I'm a beginner with Symfony, Doctrine, ... so I've tried to do the next commands and I've receive some error message I don't know how to resolve it, I've research on the web all days and I've found nothing.

The commands

```
php bin/console doctrine:schema:update -f
```

or

```
php bin/console doctrine:database:create
```

I've these error messages :

```
[Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\ConnectionException]
An exception occured in driver: SQLSTATE[08006] [7] FATAL:  role "stats_crm" does not exist

[Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOException]
SQLSTATE[08006] [7] FATAL:  role "stats_crm" does not exist

[PDOException]
SQLSTATE[08006] [7] FATAL:  role "stats_crm" does not exist
```

I don't know what do you need for the informations about my environment, I'm using PhpStorm 2016.3.2, PostgreSQL 9.6, PgAdmin 3, phpPgAdmin 5.1, WAMP 3.0.6 and PHP 5.6.25

Thank you, sorry for my bad English and I don't know if you need more information.

Comment: I don't know why, salutation does not display

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception message tells you that doctrine can't login to your database host with username `stats_crm`, because that role does not exist.

To fix that exception, you have to find the right `username` that can get you in to the database server. Then, open your `app/config/parameters.yml`, find `node` named  `database_user`, and update it accordingly (and `database_password` if necessary).

Comment: Hi Rendy, Thanks a lot it's work fine now thank you :)